# Connecting to Google Play Services crashes on devices

Tags: android, connection, google-play-services

I made a sample app to try how to connect to Google Play Services and when trying it on my mobile or tablet, it crashes when opening the app.

I know for sure the error is when trying to connect using the client.connect() because when commented, the app does not crash.

The main (and only) activity is the following, I omit the imports since compiles properly.

```
public class ry extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private GoogleApiClient client;
//GoogleApiClient

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    client.connect();  //   <- Error line


}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    // We are not connected anymore!
    Log.i("app", "connectionsuspended");
}

public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // We tried to connect but failed!


    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, 49404);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("app", e.toString());
    }

}

}
```

And also my gradle.build:

```
[...]
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.2.0'
 }
[...]
```

Any help will be greatly welcome.

Update, I will post the rellevant line of the log error, since there are no errors, only warnings and I find the following relevant.

```
07-04 12:20:15.840 5124-5192/com.example.internet.connectiontry W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9256000 but found 9080270
```

Update 2:

It seems that using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
```

instead, it does the trick and , however it crashes because of:

```
--------- beginning of crash
07-04 19:35:14.788 2245-2245/com.example.internet.connectiontry     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[...]
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.internet.connectiontry">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

According to Internet info, that metadata tag must be the first child under of application tag, however I tried several times, positions... and does not work.

Comment: You have an updated Android studio?

Comment: And updated google services on your app too?

Comment: Can you post the log error that you get?

Comment: I cannot run it on Android Studio due to Google Play Services not updated. As soon as possible I will try do to it (startResolutionForResult says me it is not updated)

Comment: About updated Android Studio, I think I have but better have to check it out. Also, any hint for updating Google Play Services on AVD on Android Studio?

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Comment: No, I wanna install an updated version on AVD of Android Studio if when executing hints me something rellevant.

Comment: Did you test my answer already?

Comment: Yes, I did but nothing. I am going to update the answer with the log error.

Comment: I updated with new info, with the troubles with manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
      if(client != null){
         client.connect();
      }
}
```

Check whether Google play services is installed on device:

```
GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            // do your task
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services required!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked  whether Google play services is installed on device?? Check my updated answer

Comment: I used your updated answer, and yes, it is installed, however it keeps on crashing...

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `onCreate`  method

```
if (client == null) {
 client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
           .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
           .build();
}
```

and add `@Override` to your `onConnectionFailed` method